# Updating objects within array in MongoDB with mongoose

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm trying to update objects within an array in a document. The objects are not subdocuments and therefore don't have a unique ID. I've tried looking at various methods to do this but it just doesn't seem to have any effect (as in, nothing happens - no errors, but the document doesn't update.

Probably easier just to show the code. First, here's an example of a document in this collection:

```
{
    _id: 123,
    //other fields go here
    submissions: [
        {
            submission: 1,
            downloaded: null, //This should be an ISODate when populated
            assessor: null,   //This should be an ObjectID when populated
            feedbackUploaded: null, //This should also be an ISODate
            path: '401Test1.doc',
            assessorNotes: null //This should be a string when populated
        },
        {
            submission: 2,
            downloaded: null,
            assessor: null,
            feedbackUploaded: null,
            path: '401Test2.doc',
            assessorNotes: null
        }
    ]
}
```

And now my mongoose query (within an express route):

```
const unit = req.body.unit; //e.g. 123
const submission = req.body.submission // e.g. 2
const date = Date.now();

Unit.update({ "_id": unit, "submissions.submission": submission }, {
        $set: {
            'submissions.assessorNotes': req.body.assessorComments,
            'submissions.feedbackUploaded': date,
            'submissions.assessor': req.body.assessor
        }, function(err){
            //callback
        }
    })
```

I've also tried this using `$` notation in the `$set` command i.e. `'submissions.$.assessorNotes': req.body.assessorComments'` but this doesn't seem to work either.

Where am I going wrong?!

Cheers!

Chris

Comment: it should work with the positional operator `$`. are you sure you have a match? if you do just `find` with these params, do you find the document?

Comment: Tried running a `find` and it returned the correct document, so it looks as though I'm getting a match - it just isn't updating. Have tried with `findOneAndUpdate` as well - same problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just tested this with the positional operator as mentioned above by TomG in a shell.

```
> db.foo.find().pretty()
{
    "_id" : 123,
    "submissions" : [
        {
            "submission" : 1,
            "downloaded" : null,
            "assessor" : null,
            "feedbackUploaded" : null,
            "path" : "401Test1.doc",
            "assessorNotes" : null
        },
        {
            "submission" : 2,
            "downloaded" : null,
            "assessor" : null,
            "feedbackUploaded" : null,
            "path" : "401Test2.doc",
            "assessorNotes" : null
        }
    ]
}
```

Then I ran the update command:

```
db.foo.update(
  { _id: 123, "submissions.submission": 2 }, 
  { $set: {
    "submissions.$.assessorNotes": "testAssessorNotes",
    "submissions.$.feedbackUploaded": new Date(),
    "submissions.$.assessor": "testAssessor"
  } }
)
```

Results are as follows:

```
{
    "_id" : 123,
    "submissions" : [
        {
            "submission" : 1,
            "downloaded" : null,
            "assessor" : null,
            "feedbackUploaded" : null,
            "path" : "401Test1.doc",
            "assessorNotes" : null
        },
        {
            "submission" : 2,
            "downloaded" : null,
            "assessor" : "testAssessor",
            "feedbackUploaded" : ISODate("2016-10-26T15:33:09.573Z"),
            "path" : "401Test2.doc",
            "assessorNotes" : "testAssessorNotes"
        }
    ]
}
```

Edit: My hunch is that the error could also be with the update in Mongoose, you could try changing both to the positional operators, as well as using [findOneAndUpdate](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#query_Query-findOneAndUpdate) if it fits your needs instead of update.

Please try this query for Mongoose:

```
Unit.update(
    { "_id": unit, "submissions.submission": submission }, 
    { $set: {
        'submissions.$.assessorNotes': req.body.assessorComments,
        'submissions.$.feedbackUploaded': date,
        'submissions.$.assessor': req.body.assessor
    } }, function(err, result) {
        //callback
    }
});
```

Comment: Just tried `findOneAndUpdate` and appear to have the same problem. When I do a `find` as Tom suggested, it returns the correct document so it looks as though I have a match. Is there another alternative to `update` and `findOneAndUpdate`? Perhaps using `save` or something similar?

Comment: You could use find/findOne to return your object in the callback, then modify the value and finally call the save function.  Are you also using the positional operator in your $set ?

Comment: I added a query for Mongoose, can you please try that and see if it works?  I noticed a missing brace at the end of your set command.

Comment: OK, I've managed to solve it - I'll add the solution shortly, but basically it involved doing a `findById` on the document, then looping through the submission array, looking for a match on `submission` and then using `save` - so similar to your suggestion. Very strange that `update` didn't work in the first place - is this a common bug with mongoose?

Comment: of course it will work with iterating and save, but it should work also with `update` and `findOneAndUpdate` and `findByIdAndUpdate`. Are you sure your `req.body` parameters are fine? do you get any error?

Comment: Aha! That's worked! So it all came down to a missing brace! Thanks for that - much nicer than messing around with iterations and saves! Strange that it didn't throw an error, but not to worry, it's sorted now!